# Configuring a controller using Sencha Architect 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm trying to achieve something fairly simple: use a controller to attach an event to a specific control, but am struggling to represent this using Sencha Architect.

I have a button named "Login-Button-Login".

In my controller, if I have the code:

```
config: {
    control: {
        "button": {
            tap: 'onButtonTap'
        }
    }
},

onButtonTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    Ext.Msg.alert("onButtonTap fired");
},
```

The the button works as expected. This is fine, but obviously it will apply to all buttons. I add a reference to "Login-Button-Login" (not my choice of name!):

```
config: {
    refs: {
        loginButtonTap: 'Login-Button-Login'
    },

    control: {
        "button": {
            tap: 'onButtonTap'
        },
        "Login-Button-Login": {
            tap: 'onButtonTap2'
        }
    }
},
```

**But how can I now use the reference "loginButtonTap" as an item in the control object?** Whatever I try using the Sencha Architect controls I just end up with "Login-Button-Login" being referenced directly.

Relatedly, how can I link this controller to the "Login" view which contains the button? Surely I don't need to use full selectors for each reference? Clearly even if I could make this work, it currently would not function as Login-Button-Login needs to reference the "Login" view.

Comment: If you explain more clearly.. you will get the answer

Comment: @Viswa which part is not clear? I've laid everything out as clearly as possible.

Comment: Login-Button-Login is a id or ItemId or action ?.. what you mean "how can i now use the reference "loginButtonTap" as an item in the control object".. do you want to get button object in controller ?

Comment: Login-Button-Login is the id of an element in the GUI. Not in the controller object, in the `control` section of the config. What I want is the code given by the second post in this link: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?269874-Confusion-relating-to-use-of-controller-config-gt-control-object - the code is fine, but Sencha Architect does not allow this, and if I edit the file then reopen in SA, the changes are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `id` (or `itemId`) of the control as the value of the `controlQuery` in event handler config:

```
config: {
    control: {
        "#btnWhatever": {
            tap: 'onWhateverTap'
        },
}
```

I prefer to use this method of attaching events to elements, since I am too lazy to do double work - specify the reference to the button, and then specify that reference in event handlers `controlQuery`. `onWhateverTap` gets the reference to the button as an argument and most of the time you do not need that reference anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - so why is it recommended to use refs?

Comment: You can read about them here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/controllers It is mostly the same, except for the automatically generated getter and some additional functionality, like `autoCreate`.